# Java "Gradient frame effect" to a BufferedImage via WritableRaster class and setSample method

Tags: java, gradient, frame, bufferedimage

I need a suggestion: I would like to know, in general,    the algorithm to follow to obtain the "gradient frame effect" to be    applied to a BufferedImage, manipulating the Raster of the image    (WritableRaster class and setSample method). For example, I have this image:

Input:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpkSb.jpg]

I would like to get this:

Gradient frame effect:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD6sX.jpg]

How can I proceed?

Comment: I added a second question (number 2) which I would like your response to

Comment: If you have an additional question, then post a new question. Questions on Stack Overflow should be focused on one thing only. I have rolled back the edit that added your second question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `AlphaComposite` to paint over top of the original image with an appropriate transparency/opaqueness to give you different effects for the border.

The `RadialGradientPaint` will give you the spot light effect by using full transparency in the center and gradually transitioning to the black border.

The following will paint a black border around the image:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class ClipImageBorder
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("mickeyred.jpg"));

        //  Set up the properties of the RadialGradientPaint

        int border = 20;
        int width = image.getWidth() - (2 * border);
        int height = image.getHeight() - (2 * border);
        Rectangle2D  bounds = new Rectangle2D.Double(border, border, width, height);

        float[] dist = {0.0f, 0.8f, 1.0f};
        Color transparent = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Color[] colors = {transparent, transparent, Color.BLACK};
        RadialGradientPaint p = new RadialGradientPaint(bounds, dist, colors, MultipleGradientPaint.CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE);

        //  Use the AlphaComposite to paint the border

        Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
        g2.setPaint(p);
        g2.setComposite( AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.0f) );
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        g2.dispose();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe `AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER` with full opacity is the default Porter/Duff rule (default composite for a `Graphics`). It's the `RadialGradientPaint` with transparent color doing all the magic here. Otherwise +1 

Comment: Yes, playing with the alpha value of the composite will allow you to achieve other effects, if desired.